# Python: Where do I find packages like "gf" for the Anaconda Navigator and how do I install them? Python Version 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, gf

this is my first question here;-)

I am using Python 3.6 via Anaconda Navigator (1.7) and that program shows a list of packages when I click Environments. 
Are these packages directly useable or do I have to start any process therefor?
In a script I want to use the import-function for the package "gf", this one is not in the list above. 
Where do I find it in a compatible form and how can I make it useable?

Anaconda says it has to be .yaml or .yml (Conda environment files) or .txt (Conda explicit specification files or pip requirement files)

I know the other way with the command line and WHL files, but Anaconda does not seem to have any command line as the kind-of-user-guide says. 
First I tried renaming other install files to .txt, but Anaconda just took ages and got a serious problem that I had to restart it several times. 
I also tried to check https://anaconda.org/conda-forge for "gf", but it seems not available there.

Best Regards

Comment: There are many things to cover, I can’t type everything know, so I’ll start with only two questions: Where does the blurb about file formats come from, and which _kind-of-user-guide_ are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

By GF, do you mean Grammatical Framework (https://www.grammaticalframework.org/)? If so, then you can't install it via Anaconda. Maybe you would be interested in one of the following options?

### Jupyter kernel for GF

From https://github.com/kwarc/gf_kernel#readme:

> `gf_kernel` is a Jupyter kernel for the Grammatical Framework (GF) . It allows you to write grammars and using them for parsing/translating/... all in one notebook, which makes it great for demos and teaching, but also for small experiments with GF.

You need to have GF installed: see https://www.grammaticalframework.org/download/index.html for options.

### Using GF grammars from an external Python program

Python bindings to the PGF library are included in the GF binary, so if you have Mac or Ubuntu, the easiest way is to [download the binary](https://www.grammaticalframework.org/download/index.html).
For other systems, see this [blog post](https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2019/12/12/embedding-grammars.html#installation-in-python) for how to install.